# Retrieve Just JWT token from sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, parsing

I have a value inside **sessionStorage** called **user** which contains amongst other info the JWT token. How do I isolate just the **JWT** token from the value using **javascript**?

```
user = sessionStorage.getItem('user');
value = JSON.parse(user)
value.token
```

Is there a way to perform this cleaner?

Comment: Why do you think your current approach is not _clean_?

Comment: `value.token` does nothing you kow

Comment: @Bravo it retrieves the token value stored in value

Comment: yeah, and does nothing with it

Comment: @Bravo what I do with it wasnt relevant to the question

Comment: Oh, I thought you asked for cleaner code - cleaner code would not need that line as it does nothing - without knowing what you're doing, the "cleaner" code would be to omit that line as it does nothing - and the first two lines can be one, like `value = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('user'))` since you never need the `user` JSON anyway